# Enable anonymous authentication to certain path for ASP.NET MVC windows auth enabled app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-config

I have a web application which has Windows Authentication enabled but i want to enable anonymous access to certain paths.

Is there a way i can do that from web.config?

Something like this. (Adding this on web.config throws error that i cannot override it)

```
<location path="/dir/path">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Current web.config

```
<system.web>

<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" explicit="true" debug="false">     
</compilation>

<customErrors mode="On" />

<authentication mode="Windows" />

<identity impersonate="false" />

<authorization>
<allow users="*" />
</authorization>

<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <remove name="HttpPost" />
    <remove name="HttpGet" />
  </protocols>
</webServices>    

</system.web>

<location path="_user/pages">
    <system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: should the first `<authorization>` section be `<deny users="*"/>` ? Otherwise everyone has access to everything anyway

Answer (score 0):

I use this all the time for the `NotAuthorized` view of an app that is otherwise completely behind authentication.

```
<system.webServer>
    <authorization>
        <allow roles="NormalUser, Admin" />
        <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
</system.webServer>    

<location path="NotAuthorized">
    <system.webServer>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Change to `<system.web>` for IIS 6

Comment: This doesn't work. I still get 401 back for the anonymous request.

Comment: @user3685509 hmm, it should work. you may want to post your whole `Web.Config` then (minus `<appSettings>` and `<connectionStrings>`). including which /dir/path you're attempting it to work for

Comment: I think the authorization only works when you have form auth. When widnows auth is enabled it always seems to redirect to 401. I have posted the full web.config

Comment: The `<authorization>` section works for Windows Auth as well. You can see examples of that here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323176

Comment: That article in a way explains why it's not working :). The user has to get past the authentication for authorization to kick in.  After that you determine which user has access to a resource by restricting by domain user names or groups. I wanted to not have authentication at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
<location path="MyController/MyAction">
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

For clarification look @ [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.allowanonymousattribute(v=vs.108).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.allowanonymousattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when windows auth is enabled. I always get a 401 in that scenario